# Responsive navigation bar (full screen to mobile)

Tags: html, css, navigation, navbar, nav

**EDIT: I should mention that I can only use CSS.

I am having trouble with my navigation bar. Basically, it works perfectly in mobile view, but can't seem to get it to work in full screen mode. The follow diagrams are examples of what I want to try to achieve:

FULL SCREEN MODE:
[image: FULL SCREEN MODE]

MOBILE MODE:

[image]

THE HTML, CSS IN LINK:

```
    <nav>
    <div class="navigation">
        <a href="#" class="logo"></a>
        <input class="menu-btn" type="checkbox" id="menu-btn" name="menu-button" />
        <label class="menu-icon" for="menu-btn"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#Pages/about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events and Workshops</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="Pages/upcomingevents.html">Upcoming Events</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Pages/comingworkshops.html">Upcoming Workshops</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Pages/request.html">Request an Event or Workshop</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Resources</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="Pages/allresources.html">All Resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Pages/nutrition.html">Nutrition Resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Pages/physical.html">Physical Activity Resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Pages/mental.html">Mental Health Resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Pages/spiritual.html">Spiritual Health Resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Pages/social.html">Social Health Resources</a></li>
                    <li><a href="Pages/medical.html">Medical Health Resources</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav
```

Full HTML + CSS in this link: https://jsfiddle.net/fkw2h0b6/

Thank you!

Comment: Using bootstrap is not an option?

Comment: Seems like toggler not working on code. Where is `toggler` `collapse` ?  Yours bootstrap code in simple that's causing the problem.  Use `dropdown` .Try this examples this may help you to do so ! https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: @Granny No only CSS please :(